# Defining key sequences in Evil-mode Emacs

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts, vi, elisp, key-mapping

I couldn't find any instructions on defining key sequences in the Evil doc.

The example given by the developers only covers a single key.

```
(define-key evil-normal-state "w" 'foo)
```

What do I need to do, if I want to define "gv" in the normal mode or ";RET" in the insert mode?

In Vim, for example, I just do:

```
imap ;<cr> <end>;<cr>
map gv :tabprev<cr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Evil wiki page](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil#toc9) suggests using [elscreen.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsLispScreen) to emulate Vim's tabs:

```
(load "elscreen" "ElScreen" t)

(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-w t") 'elscreen-create) ;creat tab
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-w x") 'elscreen-kill) ;kill tab

(define-key evil-normal-state-map "gv" 'elscreen-previous) ;previous tab
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "gt" 'elscreen-next) ;next tab
```

Similarly you could define:

<strike>`(define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "; <return>") 'move-end-of-line)`</strike>

This emulates `imap ;<cr> <end>;<cr>`. If you press <kbd>;</kbd> followed by <kbd>Return</kbd> then the cursor will jump to the end of the line and insert a semicolon. I would have liked to make it a little more generic, but I'm missing a key function.

```
(define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd ";") 'insert-or-append)

(defun insert-or-append ()
  "If the user enters <return>, then jump to end of line and append a semicolon,
   otherwise insert user input at the position of the cursor"
  (interactive)
  (let ((char-read (read-char-exclusive))
        (trigger ";"))
    (if (eql ?\r char-read)
        (progn
          (end-of-line)
          (insert trigger))
      (insert (this-command-keys)))))
```

Comment: (define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "; <return>") 'move-end-of-line) disables insertion of regular semicolon as Emacs expects another key and I see ;- in the minibuffer. I guess to fix it I need to use (read-event) in the command that is mapped to ";" instead of defining a key sequence, but I'm not sure how to use correctly.

Comment: @MarkT. You're right... I'll have to dig into the Emacs documentation to hack up a function that does what you want.

Comment: This works perfectly. I'll sign up to upvote. Thank you.